# Elasticsearch DSL, store fields and dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-dsl

I have some fields with known mapping and some unknown, I want to store them.
Mapping:

```
class MyDoctype(DocType):
  ...
  known_field = String(index='not_analyzed')
  ...

  unknown_dict = Nested() # How can I store this dict ???
```

This should be possible as ElasticSearch 2.x can handle this mixed mapping.
Is ES dsl based on strict mappings behind the scene ?
I also looked at the [persistence](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html) docs but it seems to rely on strong mappings everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object`.
tested on `Elasticsearch` 6.x, `Elasticsearch-dsl` 6.x

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Object

class MyDoctype(DocType):
  ...
  known_field = String(index='not_analyzed')
  ...

  unknown_dict = Object()
```